# Showing an image View dynamically

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout

I am doing following things

1- Using a button opening File Explorer to choose a specific file.
2- When file is selected it is copied to my app folder.
3- The Number of files attached to that user is increased by one.

Now i want to add this receipt in a small image view under the button. Suppose i run the application and added two images using button. Now a small view of these images should be displayed beneath the button. (I need to store these images in database too so i can use them whenever i want) Now as much as the images are, i need to display images beneath the button

How can i do that

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

Simply have a linearlayout in your xml, where you want to display image, 
Get reference of LinearLayout in your activity by:

```
LinearLayout llContatiner=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.llCOntainer);
```

when you have copied image, create an ImageView by:

```
ImageView imgView = new ImageView(mContext);
imgView.setBitmap(img);
// or imgView.setDrawable(img);
llContainer.addView(imgView);
```